# what is an increasing function

Tags: functions

I read this question:[what is a function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087412/what-is-a-function)

Here comes my question,
Can we call following a increasing function (or may not even a function):

$$
f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\\
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x,& x\in[0,1/3]\\
2x,& x\in[2/3,1]\\
\end{cases}
$$

For my understanding, I would say this it not even a function since there's no **image** of domain $(1/3,2/3)$, am I right?

Comment: Well it is a function, but certainly not one defined over $[0,1]$, rather $[0, 1/3] \cup [2/3, 1]$ (the image domain is also smaller than $\mathbbm (R) $). That being said, it is an increasing function on both sub-intervals, hence on the entire definition domain as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a relation which is not a function. However, if we say that $f:[0,1/3]\cup[2/3,1]\to\mathbb R$, this is a perfectly good function, and it is increasing.

Comment: so the discontinuous points of an increasing function cannot be interval,right?

Comment: Yes. An increasing function cannot be discontinuous over an entire interval; it can only have a countable number of discontinuities.