# Variable versus Function

Tags: functions, notation

When we write $y=f(x)$ what do we mean? Would we call $y$ a function of $x$ as well? $y=f(x)$ would represent geometrically a curve in the xy-plane, but other than that I don't understand why we would write something like that.

Comment: See [Lambda Calculus and functional application](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lambda-calculus/).

Comment: We have the "formal" notation: $f : A \to B$ to denote a *function*. We have the usual notation $f(x)$ the denote a single-argument function. We have the $f(a)=b$ notation to denote the fact that the $b$ is the value of the function $f$ for argument $a$. And we have traditions: one of them (very old) is that originated with representation of functions with Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: You can see also the post: [What is a function ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087412/what-is-a-function)

Comment: See [Function: notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Notation) and [History of the function concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_function_concept).

Answer (score 2):

That depends on part on what $f(x)$ is. Suppose $f(x) = x^2 + 1$. Then, if $y = 5$, we have $f(2) = 5 = y$. But we also have $f(-2) = 5 = y$ as well, so a lot of values of $y$ are matched to two values of $x$. If you're limited to "real" numbers, then some values of $y$ don't match to *any* values of $x$ at all.

Now suppose $f(x) = x + 1$. This is what you humans like to call a "one-to-one" function. If $y = f(x)$, then each value of $y$ matches to precisely one value of $x$.

That's the only context I've seen that notation in, explaining one-to-one functions, e.g., http://www.mathwords.com/h/horizontal_line_test.htm