# Image of the function $y=\sqrt x$

Tags: calculus, radicals

Let us take the function
$$
y= \sqrt x.
$$

Of course we must say that $x$ must be $\ge 0$ (domain $[0, +\infty]$).
Let us suppose that we should determine its image.

I extract $x$ and obtain
$$
x= y^2.
$$

Now I observe that $y$ can assume any value in $\mathbb R$.
BUT it is not true. $y$ is $\ge0$.

Can anyone explain me why? Where is the mistake I do?

Nick

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! That  IS simply because, of the two square roots of a positive number, $\sqrt x$ denotes, by convention, the positive one.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1569629/42969.

Comment: More related questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1448885?

Comment: @MartinR The first two you have proposed as duplicate, surely related, are more on precalculus issues. Maybe there exists some othe duplicate more suitable as a target.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/26363/42969

Comment: @MartinR I didn't find among the previous question given a good target duplicate for this question. Indeed, here the OP is aware that $y=\sqrt x \ge 0$, the doubt is about the steps used to obtain the image. Could you please me indicate what is the current target duplicate you have selected. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The function $y=\sqrt x$ is indeed, by definition, the inverse function of the function $y=x^2$, defined in the domain $x\in [0,\infty)$ indeed assuming $x\in \mathbb R$ the latter doesn’t admit an inverse.

See also the related

- [Confusion about the definition of function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1071944/505767)
- [What exactly is a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2862927/505767)
- [Why is $\sin : \mathbb{R} \to [-5,5] $ different from $\sin : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2866897/505767)

Comment: And this has indeed been asked and answered many times before: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1448885.

Comment: @MartinR I supposed the subject is not new, I'll take a look to the target duplicates you have posted. Thanks